# How do I get rid of a random new line in the middle of a line in a text file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code will take the contents of 'out.txt' and append it to the end of 'fixed_inv.txt' in the form of a new file, 'concat.txt' based on
a shared path.

In the 'concat.txt' file, I am getting a few rows (out of thousands) that seem to have a random new line in the middle of said line.

For instance, a line is supposed to look like:

```
122 abc.def.com Failed to get CIFS shares with error code -2147024891.  None Non-supported share access type.   0   Unkonwn NULL    bluearc Different Security Type (1), Access is denied. (1354), Pruned. Different security type (21), The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built. (3713), Could not convert the name of inner file or directory (27)
```

But instead, I have a few looking like:

```
122 abc.def.com Failed to get CIFS shares with error code -2147024891. None 
Non-supported share access type.   0   Unkonwn NULL    bluearc Different Security Type (1), Access is denied. (1354), Pruned. Different security type (21), The inherited access control list (ACL) or access control entry (ACE) could not be built. (3713), Could not convert the name of inner file or directory (27)
```

I have tried to fix this in my code below, but for some reason the code runs but does not fix the issue - which is to backspace the misplaced half line back or to get rid of the random new line.

```
class Error:
    def __init__ (self, path, message): #self = new instance of class
        self.path = path
        self.message = message #error message
        self.matched = False #has the path from out.txt been matched to the path of fixed_inv.txt?

def open_files(file1, file2, file3):
    try:
        f1 = open(file1, 'r')
    except IOError: 
        print("Can't open {}".format(file1))
        return None, None, None #you can't just open one file you have to open all
    else:
        try:
            f2 = open(file2, 'r')
        except IOError: 
            print("Can't open {}".format(file2))
            f1.close()
            return None, None, None
        else:
            try:
                f3 = open(file3, 'w')
            except IOError: 
                print("Can't open {}".format(file3))
                f1.close()
                f2.close()
                return None, None, None
            else:
                return f1, f2, f3

def concat(file1, file2, file3):
    errors = {} #key: path, value: instance of class Error
    f1, f2, f3 = open_files(file1, file2, file3)
    prevLine = "" #NEW
    if f1 is not None: #if file one is able to open...
        with f1:
            for line_num, line in enumerate(f1): #get the line number and line
                line = line.replace("\\", "/") #account for the differences in backslashes
                tokens = line.strip().split(': ') #strip white spaces, split based on ':'
                if len(tokens) != 3: #if there's less than two tokens...
                    print('Error on line {} in file {}: Expected three tokens, but found {}'.format(line_num + 1, file1, len(tokens))) #error
                else: #NEW
                    if line.startswith('Non-supported'): #NEW
                        Prevline = line
                        Prevline = line.strip('\n') #NEW
                    else:
                        errors[tokens[1]] = Error(tokens[1], tokens[2]) 
        with f2: 
            with f3:
                for line_num, line in enumerate(f2):
                    line = line.replace("\\", "/").strip() #account for the differences in backslashes
                    tokens_2 = line.strip().split('\t') #strip white spaces, split based on tab
                    if len(tokens_2) < 4: #if we are unable to obtain the path by now since the path should be on 3rd or 4th index
                        print('Error on line {} in file {}: Expected >= 4 tokens, but found {}'.format(line_num + 1, file2, len(tokens_2)))
                        f3.write('{}\n'.format(line))
                    else: #if we have enough tokens to find the path...
                        if tokens_2[3] in errors: #if path is found in our errors dictionary from out.txt...
                            line.strip('\n')
                            path = tokens_2[3] #set path to path found
                            msg = errors[path].message #set the class instance of the value to msg                    
                            errors[path].matched = True #paths have been matched
                            f3.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(line, msg)) #write the line and the error message to concat
                        else: #if path is NOT found in our errors dictionary from out.txt...
                            f3.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(line, 'None'))  
                            print('Error on line {} in file {}: Path {} not matched'.format(line_num + 1, file2, tokens_2[3])) #found in fixed_inv.txt,
                            #but not out.txt

                """for e in errors: #go through errors
                    if errors[e].matched is False: #if no paths have been matched
                        print('Path {} from {} not matched in {}'.format(errors[e].path, file1, file2)) #found in out.txt, but not in fixed_inv
                        f3.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(line, 'No error present'))

def main():

    file1 = 'out.txt'
    file2 = 'fixed_inv.txt'
    file3 = 'test_concat.txt'

    concat(file1, file2, file3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any ideas/advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: read file line by line and check if there is more than one `\n` char in one line then remove the first one if the check is True.

Comment: @Mick_, but by definition a line can never contain more than one newline. Because then it's not a line, it's two lines.

Comment: @Kevin ..Good point there. In that case check if the line ends with None and next one starts with not-supported unless all lines look different.

Comment: As a side note, you could replace all that complicated logic for guaranteeing you always have three open files or none with a single try/except and a single with on all three open calls.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing newline chars before writing it.

**Ex:**

```
f3.write('{}\n'.format(line.strip().replace("\n", "")))
f3.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(line.strip().replace("\n", ""), msg.replace("\n", "")))
f3.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(line.strip().replace("\n", ""), 'None'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can fix this on the output side, it will obviously be a lot easier and more robust. But if you can’t, what you’re doing is a start in the right direction. You just want to:

- Use `prevline + line` in place of `line` the first time.
- Set `prevline = “”` in successful cases.
- Do the check for an incomplete line before reading an error instead of after.
- Distinguish too few tokens (may be an incomplete line) from too many (definitely an error) instead of trying to treat them the same.
- Possibly (depending on actual input) replace new lines with some other white space instead of nothing.

Also, you may want to wrap this logic up in a generator function that you can reuse. Something like this:

```
def tokenizing(lines):
    prevline = ""
    for line in lines:
        line = prevline + line
        line = line.strip_logic_goes_here()
        tokens = tokenize_logic_goes_here(line)
        if len(tokens) > REQUIRED_TOKENS:
            raise AppropriateException()
        elif len(tokens) == REQUIRED_TOKENS:
            yield line, tokens
            prevline = ""
        else:
            prevline = line
    if not prevline: return
    tokens = tokenize_logic_goes_here()
    if len(tokens) != REQUIRED_TOKENS:
        raise AppropriateException()
    yield line, tokens
```

Then you can just write;

```
for line, tokens in tokenizing(f1):
```

Comment: When running the generator in main, how would I call it? I know I would put tokenizing(INSERT SOMETHING HERE), but I'm not sure what. Can I also use the generator alone? I'm not familiar with this and your code is way more advanced than what I'm used to (I've been coding for a few weeks only), so pardon my multiple questions.

Comment: @Ruth The last line shows how to use it—just loop over `tokenizing(f1)` instead of `f1`. But if you don't understand it at all, it's probably better to not do this, even if it means repeating yourself a little. It might still be helpful to other people with similar problems to yours, but it won't be helpful to you to include a bunch of code you can't debug or extend.

Comment: Gotcha! I'm gonna learn about generators and see if I can understand further, I really want to understand. Is this instead of some of the code I have, or in addition? And do I replace _for line_num, line in enumerate(f1):_ with _for line, tokens in tokenizing(f1):_?

Comment: @Ruth If you want to learn about generators, after a basic tutorial of some kind, google David Beazley Generator Tricks. Like most abstractions, generators seem a little baffling until you have an “aha moment” where you get what the point is, and Beazley’s presentation does a great job of giving many people that aha. But meanwhile, you can `enumerate` any iterable. If you want “repaired” line numbers, use `for num, (line, tokens) in enumerate(tokenizing(f1)):`; if you want original line numbers, change `tokenizing` to do `for num, line in enumerate(lines):` and `yield num, line, tokens`.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look into that! For _for num, (line, tokens) in enumerate(tokenizing(f1)):_, what do I put after that since now everything is taken care of tokenizing? I'm close to understanding!

Comment: @Ruth it’ll be pretty close to what’s in your inner if-else.

Comment: Tried your code but it didn't do anything. Can we message?